# PegKit string interpolation

Tags: pegkit

I'm using PegKit to build a simple domain specific interpreted language.

I essentially have everything working other than interpolated strings.

The idea is to achieve some kind of rule like this:

```
atom = Number | stringLiteral | referenceType;
stringLiteral = "'"! (~"'" | "{"! expression "}"!)*  "'"!;
referenceType = Word ('.' Word)*;
```

where the 'expression' production is defined already.

I've inserted some logic here that builds up a string from the tokens I need. If we come across an expression, I evaluate it and add it to the string that's being built.

The atom and reference type productions are parsing perfectly.

But if i try parse something like 'hello', when the atom rule is run, the token produced is always of the built-in Word type.

I've tried replacing the single quote with dollar signs and other character combinations to represent the start and end of strings but it never matches.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

Are you sure that the erroneous `'hello'` tokens produced are of type `Word`? I suspect they may actually of type `QuotedString`… The default behavior of `PKTokenizer` would be to produce a `QuotedString` token for any single- or double-quoted string.

To achieve the result you're looking for, you must alter the **tokenizerState** of `PKTokenizer` for the apostrophe (single-quote). By default, this is `PKQuoteState`, but you will need to change that to `PKSymbolState` (the tokenizers `-symbolState` property) so that apostrophes are recognized as single-character tokens of type `Symbol` instead of the beginning of a multi-character token of type `QuotedString`.

You can do this in an **Action** at the top of your grammar (or wherever you are configuring your tokenizer):

```
@before {
    PKTokenizer t = self.tokenizer;
    [t setTokenizerState:t.symbolState from:'\'' to:'\''];
}
```

Now apostrophes will be tokenized as single-character `Symbol` tokens.

Comment: Thanks Todd! That seems to fix it up for me.